# Call same function using different buttons

Tags: python, tkinter

How can i call the same function using different buttons? Currently i am creating different functions for different buttons.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
window=Tk()
window.title("CNO")

def browsefunc():
    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=window,initialdir="C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Documents\\Python")
    pathlabel_lbl1.config(text=filename)

def browsefunc1():
    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=window,initialdir="C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Documents\\Python")
    pathlabel_lbl2.config(text=filename)

Browse_btn=Button(window,text="Browse",command=browsefunc)
Browse_btn.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W+E)
pathlabel_lbl1=Label(window)
pathlabel_lbl1.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)

Browse_btn=Button(window,text="Browse",command=browsefunc1)
Browse_btn.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W+E)
pathlabel_lbl2=Label(window)
pathlabel_lbl2.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter does not limit the number of times that a function can be called through different widgets. So, you can simply put the browsefunc() as the command attribute of any number of buttons. Use the following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

window=Tk()
window.title("CNO")

def browsefunc():
    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=window,initialdir="C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Documents\\Python")
    pathlabel_lbl1.config(text=filename)

def browsefunc1():
    filename=filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=window,initialdir="C:\\Users\\jyoti\\Documents\\Python")
    pathlabel_lbl2.config(text=filename)

Browse_btn=Button(window,text="Browse",command=browsefunc)
Browse_btn.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky=W+E)
pathlabel_lbl1=Label(window)
pathlabel_lbl1.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)

Browse_btn=Button(window,text="Browse",command=browsefunc)
Browse_btn.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky=W+E)
pathlabel_lbl2=Label(window)
pathlabel_lbl2.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)

window.mainloop()
```

You might sometimes wanna use `lambda` also. Although in your case it isn't required at all.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply edit the `command=browsefunc` to match your function name in both of your buttons.

Currently you have `Browse_btn=Button(window,text="Browse",command=browsefunc)` and `Browse_btn=Button(window,text="Browse",command=browsefunc1)`, so just edit the last one to have the same function name to call.

Comment: Give the `browsefunc()` function a parameter that takes the pathlabel variable name, and use that.

Comment: I think that you should go ahead and try yourself. That is the path to learning. You probably dont want to spend 90% of your development time sitting in Stack Overflow, but rather learn the language and get developing.